# MongoDb query and operation for multiple negative conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I stuck at a query. Maybe i worked so long but could you help me to find which operator i should use for this step.

Example collection

```
[
  {color: "red",size: "m"},
  {color: "red",size: "s"},
  {color: "blue",size: "m"},
  {color: "blue",size: "s"}
]
```

I want to query document which are not red and not m.

`db.foo.find({color:{$ne:'red'}, size:{$ne:'m'}})` returns only `[{color:'blue', size:'s'}]` but i want to get `[{color:'red', size:'s'},{color:'blue', size:'m'},{color:'blue', size:'s'}]`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong filter. You just need to update filter query as,

```
{"$or":[{color:{$ne:'red'}}, {size:{$ne:'m'}}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that i should stop for today :) previous part of aggregation  was like $or : [{color:'red', price:{$regex:input, $options: 'i'}},{color:'blue', size:{$regex:input, $options: 'i'}}] , for this step i want to add negatif condition ... i thought it should like (a&&b)||(a&&c) s opposite's (a'||b')&&(a'||c')